# Data corruption when memcpy from DMA

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, dma

**EDIT:**

Not sure if that's a problem or not, but here is something I've noticed about:
The rx_skbuffers are allocated in two places: once when the driver is been initialized, it calls __netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align with GPF_KERNEL, and the second time if the rx_skbuff is already freed it calls netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align (which is internally uses GPF_ATOMIC).

Shouldn't these skb allocations be called with GPF_DMA ?

==========================================================================

I'm having issues with data corruption in an Ethernet driver (for ST MAC 10/100/1000) I'm working with. The driver runs on Allwinner A20 (ARM Cortex-A7).

**Some details:**

- The driver holds a ring of Rx sk_buffers (allocated with `__netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align`).
- The data (`rx_skbuff[i]->data`) of each of the sk_buffers is mapped to the DMA using `dma_map_single`.
- The mapping has been succeed (verified with `dma_mapping_error`).

**The problem:**

After a while (minutes, hours, days... very random), kernel panics due to data corruption.

**Debugging (EDITED):**

- After digging a bit more, I found out that sometimes, after a while, one of the sk_buffer structure is been corrupted, and this may lead the program to do things it should not and thus cause the kernel to panic.
- After some more digging, I've found out that the corruption occurs after `skb_copy_to_linear_data` (which is just the same as `memcpy`). Keep in mind that this corruption doesn't occur after each call of `skb_copy_to_linear_data`, but when the corruption does occurs, it is always after the call to `skb_copy_to_linear_data`.
- When the corruption occurs, it doesn't happens on the `rx_q->rx_skbuff` of the current entry (`rx_q->rx_skbuff[entry]`). For example, if we perform the `skb_copy_to_linear_data` on `rx_q->rx_skbuff[X]`, the corrupted `sk_buff` structure will be `rx_q->rx_skbuff[Y]` (where X is not equal Y).
- It seems that the physical address of the `skb->data` (that has been allocated right before the `skb_copy_to_linear_data` call), has the same physical address of `rx_q->rx_skbuff[Y]->end`. First thing I thought is that maybe the driver doesn't know rx_q->rx_skbuff[Y] has been released, but when this collision occurs I see the rx_q->rx_skbuff[Y]->users is 1.
  ***How could it be, Any ideas ?***
- Not sure if that's a problem or not, but here is something I've noticed about:
  The rx_skbuffers are allocated in two places: once when the driver is been initialized, it calls __netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align with GPF_KERNEL, and the second time if the rx_skbuff is already freed it calls netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align (which is internally uses GPF_ATOMIC). **Shouldn't these skb allocations be called with GPF_DMA ?**

**Code:**

Here is part of the code where the corruption occurs.
The full code of the driver is from linux kernel mainline 4.19, and it can be found [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.109/source/drivers/net/ethernet/stmicro/stmmac/stmmac_main.c).
I've paste here only the part between lines 3451-3474.
Does anyone find here a wrong behavior regarning the use of the DMA-API ?

```
skb = netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align(priv->dev,
                frame_len);
if (unlikely(!skb)) {
    if (net_ratelimit())
        dev_warn(priv->device,
             "packet dropped\n");
    priv->dev->stats.rx_dropped++;
    continue;
}

dma_sync_single_for_cpu(priv->device,
            rx_q->rx_skbuff_dma
            [entry], frame_len,
            DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

// Here I check if data has been corrupted (the answer is ALWAYS NO).
debug_check_data_corruption();

skb_copy_to_linear_data(skb,
            rx_q->
            rx_skbuff[entry]->data,
            frame_len);

// Here I check again if data has been corrupted (the answer is SOMETIMES YES).
debug_check_data_corruption();

skb_put(skb, frame_len);
dma_sync_single_for_device(priv->device,
               rx_q->rx_skbuff_dma
               [entry], frame_len,
               DMA_FROM_DEVICE);
```

**Some last notes:**

- I tried to run the kernel with `CONFIG_DMA_API_DEBUG` enabled. It's is not always triggered, but when I catch the corruption by my self (with my debug fucntion), sometimes I can see that `/sys/kernel/debug/dma-api/num_errors` has been increased, and sometimes I also get this log: `DMA-API: device driver tries to sync DMA memory it has not allocated [device address=0x000000006879f902] [size=61 bytes]`
- I've also enabled the `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK` and right after I catches the data corruption event, I get this log: `kmemleak: 1 new suspected memory leaks (see /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak)`, but I still don't understand what clues it throws, although it seem to be taken from the same part of code I've pasted here (`__netdev_alloc_skb` is been called from `__netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align`). This what `/sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak` displays:

```
unreferenced object 0xe9ea52c0 (size 192):     
  comm "softirq", pid 0, jiffies 6171209 (age 32709.360s)     
  hex dump (first 32 bytes):  
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 4d 2d ea  ............@M-.  
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 d4 83 7c b3 7a 87 7c b3  ..........|.z.|.     
  backtrace:  
        [<045ac811>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x9f/0xdc  
        [<4f2b009a>] stmmac_napi_poll+0x89b/0xfc4  
        [<1dd85c70>] net_rx_action+0xd3/0x28c  
        [<1c60fabb>] __do_softirq+0xd5/0x27c  
        [<9e007b1d>] irq_exit+0x8f/0xc0  
        [<beb36a07>] __handle_domain_irq+0x49/0x84  
        [<67c17c88>] gic_handle_irq+0x39/0x68  
        [<e8f5dc30>] __irq_svc+0x65/0x94  
        [<075bc7c7>] down_read+0x8/0x3c  
        [<075bc7c7>] down_read+0x8/0x3c  
        [<790c6556>] get_user_pages_unlocked+0x49/0x13c  
        [<544d56e3>] get_futex_key+0x77/0x2e0  
        [<1fd5d0e9>] futex_wait_setup+0x3f/0x144  
        [<8bc86dff>] futex_wait+0xa1/0x198  
        [<b362fbc0>] do_futex+0xd3/0x9a8  
        [<46f336be>] sys_futex+0xcd/0x138
```

Comment: You mentioned 4.9 but linked to 4.19. Is that a typo?

Comment: My mistake, I meant 4.19. Thanks

Comment: What architecture?  Could it be CPU cache interference?  See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.147/source/Documentation/DMA-API.txt

Comment: Allwinner A20 (ARM Cortex-A7). Is there a way I can check if it's a cache interference issue ? Perhaps when the driver calls <dma_sync_single_for_cpu> it shouldn't be called with the size of <frame_len>, but with the size of <dma_buf_sz> ,which is the same size we used in  <dma_map_single> (from the documentation I don't see we need to do so).

Comment: You can try sending packets full of a known pattern.  Then look at the corrupted data to see if it has that known pattern in it.  That would tell you that you're getting DMAed data somewhere it shouldn't be.  Check the addresses in the first sync call, are they always what they should be?  Same with the length?

Comment: @TrentP I haven't mentioned it, but I've already tried what you've just suggested and the corrupted data is with the exact known pattern of data (that's why the DMA was one of my suspects). However I didn't verify yet that the address is always correct (I'm quite sure it does). As for the length, is correct for sure.

Comment: @stark, I think I've found out that the physical addresses of the rx_skbuff[entry]->data (which is mapped to the DMA) is not aligned to the cache line (I checked if the start address mod 64 is 0 - is that the right way to check it?). However, fixing the alignment didn't help... :(

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dai0228/a/

Comment: @stark Thanks! I'll read it

Comment: I think what's important is that the nothing share the same cache line with the DMA buffer.  Neither before nor after it.

Comment: @TrentP, as far as I know, you are right. That's why I made sure the mapped data (rx_skbuff[entry]->data) starts at the beginning of the cache line, and the length of the mapped data is N*cache_lines (N is an integer). So I think I'm ok, no ?

Comment: It shouldn't conflict with anything outside the cache line.  It does seem highly probable that you've got DMA clobbering a kernel data structure in RAM.  If it's not an addressed based cacheline collision, maybe it's time based.  The kernel struct was using that address, then DMA used it, but at some point in the middle both used it.  Maybe the data was kfree'ed, then allocated for DMA, then there was a use after free?  Or was the buffer freed?

Comment: @TrentP, that's exactly what I'm trying to check now. I sounds like use after free. However, it's not so easy to track after the SKB. But if we both thought the same, I think I should make the effort and try track after this rebellious SKB. Thanks, I hope to update soon.

Comment: @TrentP, and another thing I've noticed about. Not sure if that's a problem or not. The rx_skbuffers are allocated in two places: once when the driver is been initialized, it calls __netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align with GPF_KERNEL, and the second time if the rx_skbuff is already freed it calls netdev_alloc_skb_ip_align (which is internally uses GPF_ATOMIC). Shouldn't these skb allocations be called with GPF_DMA ?

Comment: Hi @J.M., we are seeing a similar problem re. stmac eth driver on 3.10.92 and ARMv7 and came accross your question. Did you have any progress since?

Comment: Hi @whoi, unfortunately I didn't find the problem... However I did solved it. My stmmac driver was patched with a PTP driver from KSZ (https://github.com/Microchip-Ethernet/EVB-KSZ9477/tree/master/KSZ/linux-drivers/ksz9897/linux-4.19/drivers/net/ethernet/micrel), and the patch was broken (somewhere.. unfortunately don't know where). So it was solved only after I've build the patch manually step by step with the latest KSZ branch. Can you describe your problem or send me a link to your post ? I will try to help. After month of digging, I think I know the Stmmac driver quite well :)